# Django project goes down intermittently

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, python-2.6

I have a django project that goes down like once a day. I have no idea why this happens and all I see on the error log is "Premature end of script headers". I recently upgraded mod_wsgi to the latest 3.3 but this still happens.

I also increased the threads to 25 and processes to 2 but still no help. I'm currently using monit to restart apache whenever it goes down but would like to fix this problem asap.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm lost..

Thank you

EDIT:
Mod_wsgi conf below

```
WSGIDaemonProcess live user=xxx group=xxx threads=25  processes=2 inactivity-timeout=10
WSGIProcessGroup live

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/hosting/wsgi/live.wsgi
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django, apache, mod_wsgi - Error: Premature end of script headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501817/django-apache-mod-wsgi-error-premature-end-of-script-headers)

Comment: Those solutions dont apply since 1) I dont have multiple python installations and 2) I've had mod_python running alongside for years with no problems

Comment: But did you follow through and read the mod_wsgi documentation which talks about other causes such as mismatched shared library versions, third party C extensions that don't run properly in sub interpreters etc etc. In short, that error would indicate the daemon process crashed. If that is all it is though, then the process should just get replaced and things carry on. There should not be a need to restart the whole of Apache. In other words, you likely have a different issue to the one sympton you quote. Supply your mod_wsgi configuration from Apache file and then may be able to comment more.

Comment: Hi Graham, I've included the mod_wsgi configuration. The inactivity-timeout part was only added when the problem started but that didnt fix it.